# listView result retrieval and waiting for user input

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I need the user to choose an item from a listView, so the program can then execute a operation based on the option chosen.

The program should not advance while and option has not been chosen. In the following code I get an error saying "index" must be declared as final, but that way I cannot change it after, and I need to.
As to make the program hold for input, is there any more elegant solution other than and infinite loop (while(true) style)?

```
int index=-1;    

final String[] values = new String[ savesList.size() ];
for (int i=0; i < savesList.size(); i++) {
    values[savesList.size()-1 - i] =  "Name: " +  fh.list()[ savesList.get(i) ].nameWithoutExtension() + "\nLast modified: " + new Date( fh.list()[i].lastModified());
}


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

saveList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
saveList.setAdapter(adapter);
saveList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        index = values.length - 1 - position;
        System.out.println(index);
    }

});

someMethod( index );
(...More Code...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `index` final and declare another variable to hold index's value and change your second variable when you have to.

```
    final int index=0;
          int temp=0;
```

inside `onItemClick()`

```
    temp=index;
```

now you can use `temp` and chenage it whenever you want.

Comment: I need to use it the other way around, i need to set it inside the listener and use it outside after.

Comment: `temp` is declared as global so you can set it inside listener and use it outside.

Comment: I tried it without final and i don't get any error. Maybe because your `values` array is `final`.

Comment: And for waiting, do you have any sugestion?

Comment: what do you mean by waiting?